# Unity - move with WASD in the way the camera is facing

Tags: unity, c#

I have this C# code for rotating the camera with the mouse:

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 100.0f;
public float clampAngle = 80.0f;

private float rotY = 0.0f; // rotation around the up/y axis
private float rotX = 0.0f; // rotation around the right/x axis

void Start()
{
    Screen.lockCursor = true;
    Vector3 rot = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    rotY = rot.y;
    rotX = rot.x;
}

void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

    Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);
    transform.rotation = localRotation;
    transform.parent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, rotY, 0.0f);
}
```

The script is on the camera, and camera object is a child to the player object.
Now I want to move the player object in the direction the camera is facing, how do I do this?

Comment: Presumably you searched through [previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172426/39518) about [implementing camera-relative](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/170264/39518) [third-person controls in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53395/39518)? How did you try modifying your player object movement code based on your research of existing tutorials and Q&A on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a *CharacterController* component to the player (the parent of the camera), and use this script:

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 100.0f;
public float clampAngle = 80.0f;

private float rotY = 0.0f; // rotation around the up/y axis
private float rotX = 0.0f; // rotation around the right/x axis

GameObject player;
public CharacterController controller;
public float speed = 6f;


void Start()
{
    Screen.lockCursor = true;
    Vector3 rot = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    rotY = rot.y;
    rotX = rot.x;

    player = this.transform.parent.gameObject; // Getting the parent object.
    controller = player.GetComponent<CharacterController>(); // You can use the getcomponent in child instead
}

void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

    Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);
    transform.rotation = localRotation;
    transform.parent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, rotY, 0.0f);

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector3 Direction = (player.transform.forward * vertical + player.transform.right * horizontal).normalized;

    controller.Move(Direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

This will move the player with the ASDW or the arrows with the speed you want (using the *speed* variable).